# Building tables using Latex

Tags: tables

I am very new to LaTex
I met it a week ago while trying to build tables of my results output from Stats
I have read a lot of documentation but I have not been able to implement many.
I discovered I can go from .csv or excel, I downloaded excel2LaTex add in and yet I not been able to use it after a lot of efforts.
Can I get clear implementable guidance, probably how to build tables from excel or csv, dummy-level guidance.
Thank you
Dr Obum

Comment: It might be easier to read the csv directly using csvsimple or pgfplotstable.  The latter is better for numerical data.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to LaTeX, the in-side of the typography magic.

What you are using seems to me more like a black-box, where you would be on the out-side, and everything is somewhat opaquely done by some "Wizard"

I would suggest you, rather to

1. open the csv with a notepad or any plain text editor,
2. replace each comma (`,`) with an ampersand (`&`)-- if possible separated by two spaces on both sides to improve readability, and then
3. include the whole data within this code:

   ```
   \begin{table}
       \begin{tabular}{l l l ...}
            ... ... ...
            ... ... ...
       \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
   ```

with so many `l`, `c` or `r`s as the number of columns in your Excel data (for left, center or right-justifying the contents).

More about this here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Tables

Answer (score 1):

At first, when I must create table I used outer tools which generate LaTeX code.This is some of them

- [Table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/)
- [LaTeX table editor](http://truben.no/table/old/)
- [LaTable - WYSIWYG editor for LATEX tables](https://ctan.org/pkg/latable/)
- [LaTeXTab: CSV/Excel to LaTeX Table](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaTeXTab) - package for Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion in three words: [R](https://www.r-project.org/), [xtable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf), [knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/).  Save the example with .Rnw extension. You can compile it easily with Rstudio or see [How to build Knitr document from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132704/how-to-build-knitr-document-from-the-command-line).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\belowcaptionskip{1ex}
\usepackage{booktabs,verbatim,parskip}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{The original CSV file:} 
% Just to make the table.csv 
<<echo=F,comment="">>=
library(xtable)
table <- data.frame(A=c(1.234,2.123,3.1416,4.44,5.001),
B=c(21,12,23,14,45)) 
row.names(table) <- c("One","Two","Tree","Four","Five") # Ahem!
write.csv(table, file = "table.csv",row.names=T)
@
\verbatiminput{table.csv}

\subsection*{The \LaTeX\ table:}
<<results="asis",echo=F>>=
tablecopy <- read.csv(file = "table.csv",  row.names = 1, check.names = F)
print(xtable(tablecopy,caption="The CSV data"), 
caption.placement="top",include.rownames=T,booktabs = TRUE)
@
\end{document}
```