# How to dynamically format data

Tags: formatting

I have a large number of text files containing data in a certain format. I want to wrap this data with a header and nicely typeset it. The way it is warped might change, so I want to do this dynamically (in the spirit of TeX). The way I tried to do it is by first defining a new command :

```
\newcommand{\structure}[3]{  
\textbf{#1} --- #2    
#3
}
```

Then calling the command with my data and parameters as arguments:

```
\structure{My Title 1}{Subtitle 1}{   
A    0.224571  -0.024053   1.077491 \\ 
B    0.124803   0.005365   3.895348 \\ 
C    0.129247   1.219604   1.804850 \\ 
D    0.142554   1.186492   1.781366 \\ 
}
```

However, the particular spacing and formatting in my data is lost this way.

How can I keep the formatting dynamic, yet retain the information in the origin format?

Comment: If R is a option for you, [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400173/11604) load a comma delimited (.csv)  to make a simple LaTeX table. The R functions `xtable` and `kable`  have a lot of formatting options for data tables. Otherwise (you cannot use  R with knitr)  take a look to the datatool LaTeX package.

Comment: You can have a look at `pgfplotstable` too

Comment: Or `cvsimple`, or (the more complex) `datatool`.