# Round values to integers of a csv tabular

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I want to know how can I round all the values from my table to integer values. The code I am using to import the csv file as a tabular in the document is the following:

```
\csvautotabular[respect underscore = true]{files/Results_RandCA_Library_Multi_SelectedPI.csv}
```

Comment: Loading the csv as a R  `data.frame` object  as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400173/11604), you can round the whole data frame  (i.e, `table <- round(table,0)`) before exporting to latex with xtable, or  just round the latex export with option `digits` (i.e. `xtable(table, digits=0, ....)`)