# incorporate R code into latex paragraph

Tags: pdftex, knitr, source

I have a large R script I am trying to source in a LaTex document and then reference output from specific dataframes created in the source code in text in a LaTex paragraph.

When I compile the PDF I receive an error message that object num_stations is not found.

A small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
You can type R commands in your \LaTeX{} document and they will be properly run and the output printed in the document.

<<>>=
opts_chunk$set(echo=F,message=F, warnings=F)

#need com_dredge, table 2.1 and num_stations from this source code
source(file="S:/Adv/Scallop Central/2018 Scallop RSA/Industry Report/Industry Report.R")

#num_stations dataframe needed for text below
num_stations
@
This is a value $\Sexpr{num_stations$Number}$.

\end{document}
```

When I run the code chunk I dont think the source line is working.  I have read a couple different options:
1.  The source file needs to be in the same folder as the knitr file.
    I tried this an got the error message cannot open the connection.
2. Type out the path in the source code.
   I also tried that and got the same message.
3.  Use

```
  opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/Users/username/path_to_project').
```

I also tried this in the code chunk in the latex file and got the same 
   message.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you looking for `verbatim` environment?

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't the problem, but spaces in path names are occasionally problematic.  Could you try a directory without any spaces?  Could you also add a minimal R file that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I wasnt sure how to provide a R file that reproduces the example because its a source file.  Do you have any suggestions?  I did try a directory with no spaces and didnt have any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo.R` (in the working directory):

```
# ---- test  ----

bah <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
```

`test.Rnw` (in the same working directory):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
<<mychuck, cache=F,echo=F>>=
read_chunk('foo.R')
@
<<test,echo=F>>=
@
<<mydata,result="asis",echo=F>>=
kable(bah, caption="my data", booktabs = TRUE)
@
The variable \verb|bah$a| is \Sexpr{combine_words(bah$a)}.
\end{document}
```

To compile the above file use Rstudio or see 
[How to build Knitr document from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132704/how-to-build-knitr-document-from-the-command-line).

> [image: mwe]

Comment: When I run your example I get the following errors: Line 5 Missing $ inserted, Line 12 Missing $ inserted and the PDF doesnt compile.  Also, my question was related to getting values from a dataframe into test using $\Sexpr{num_stations$Number}$.

Comment: @user41509  Sorry, I wrote wrongly `test.tex` instead of `test.Rnw`, but it should be a obvious mistake if you are used to compile `knitr` files.  If not, I suggest use Rstudio. Once you loaded the chunk of the external script is irrelevant if you call the whole data frame in a table of another chunk or only a variable in a `\Sexpr{}`. It should work anyway. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you - I was able to get my source code to work with my document.  This is my first time using Latex so am not familiar with the different ways to compile files.  I am using R studio.