# Is there a latex package for working with Rtex files locally

Tags: texstudio, r, knitr, overleaf

Working with Overleaf using `.Rtex` files and I love it. However, I just discovered that Overleaf does not support a lot of the R packages (e.g., `tidyverse`, `sqldf`) and does not work with large data sets. Does any one know if there is a package that would allow me to run `.Rtex` files locally (e.g. using TeXstudio or any other LaTeX editor).

Contacted Overleaf and they told me that there is no immediate solution to these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's said that you have  `foo.Rtex` in Overleaf:

1. Save locally as `foo.Rnw`.
2. Edit with Rstudio.
3. Clik on the `Compile PDF` buttom

[image: mwe]

Without Rstudio you can also compile the `.Rnw` files  [from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132724/11604) or within a raw R session, but indeed is easier in this way.