# Plotting data with linux epoch time as x axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm a latex noob and I'm trying to plot the following csv, which contains linux epoch time, which is what i want to use as x axis, and uploadtime/totalDocs which i would like to plot on the y axis. However my latex code always plots it as a single line and using xmin/xmax did not improve my situation, could you please tell me how to improve the scale and maybe link me to the relevant documentation

Thank you

[image]

```
timestamp,uploadtime,totalDocs
1650200149709,274,10000
1650200150676,618,20000
1650200151824,771,30000
1650200152994,837,40000
1650200154867,1492,50000
1650200155908,683,60000
1650200157670,1411,70000
1650200159183,1035,80000
1650200160461,939,90000
1650200161664,851,100000

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=timestamp, y=uploadtime, col sep=comma] {PICS/1_container_load_logs_edit.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy but powerful alternative is let to R draw the tikz plot:

[image: mwe]

**MWE**:

Notes: (1) `filecontents` is omitted assuming that `data.csv` is already on disc once tested the other answer (2) The file name  must have the extension `.Rmd` to be [compiled with knitr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132724/11604) in Rstudio.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<theplot, dev='tikz', echo=F, fig.align='center', fig.dim=c(5, 3)>>=
df <- read.csv("data.csv",header=T)
df$timestamp2 <-  df$timestamp  - df$timestamp[1] 
plot(df$timestamp2, df$uploadtime, las=1,  ylim=c(0,1500), bty="n",  
     xlab=paste("Time Stamp (starting at $",    format(df$timestamp[1], scientific=T) , "$ )"), 
     ylab="Upload Time", type = "b", pch=21, bg=rainbow(10,start=.4, end=0), lwd=4, col="blue")
@
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that `pgfplots` has problems because your x values are very large. Using the floating point package `xfp` and shifting the x values is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
timestamp,uploadtime,totalDocs
1650200149709,274,10000
1650200150676,618,20000
1650200151824,771,30000
1650200152994,837,40000
1650200154867,1492,50000
1650200155908,683,60000
1650200157670,1411,70000
1650200159183,1035,80000
1650200160461,939,90000
1650200161664,851,100000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [
    x expr={\fpeval{\thisrow{timestamp} - 1650200149709}},
    y=uploadtime,
    col sep=comma,
] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, thats a nice workaround :D, kinda bummed that I can't do it with tikzpicture