# Syntax highlighting doesn't work after percent symbol %

Tags: minted, highlighting, r, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to highlight my `R` code using `minted` package. However, after `%`, a few lines didn't get highlighted.

When I delete `%` problem disappears.

My code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{R}
> quantile(x_2, 0.75)
75%
270.745
> quantile(x_2, 0.25)
25%
105.35 
> quantile(x_2, 0.75) - quantile(x_2, 0.25)
75%
165.395 
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}{R}
> quantile(x_2, 0.75)
75
270.745
> quantile(x_2, 0.25)
25
105.35 
> quantile(x_2, 0.75) - quantile(x_2, 0.25)
75%
165.395 
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Maybe you want to use `\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{R}` and then replace all `%` by `|\%|`. This will give percent signs in black, though, but you can use `\textcolor` to achieve the correct color.

Answer (score 2):

You could also preprocess the code with Knitr, see [How to build Knitr document from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132704/how-to-build-knitr-document-from-the-command-line) for example. Code:

`yourfile.Rnw`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\section{Quantiles}
<<quantile-examples, eval=TRUE>>=
x_2 <- c(0,105.35,150,270.745,300)
quantile(x_2, 0.75)
quantile(x_2, 0.25)
quantile(x_2, 0.75) - quantile(x_2, 0.25)
@
See the \textcolor{blue}{colored} examples above.
\end{document}
```

Compile in the terminal with:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('yourfile.Rnw')"
```

This will produce a file `yourfile.tex`.
After running LaTeX on that file the pdf looks as follows:

[image]