# How do I write a script (in Windows) that removes all the temporary LaTeX files in Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-latex, cleanup

Maybe my title is not so clear; I Googled a lot about cleaning up temporary files after a PDF is generated, and find it is not recommand to remove it completely in each compile.

I do want to remove it in the final with one-or-two key press in Vim.

So my question is: *Can we add some code to `_vimrc` such that I can define which kind of file shall be removed after the compile? (I mean success compile, auto-remove, at least when I ask to remove it by press key short.)*

I hope it will work both on Windows and Unix systems. (Maybe needing different **code**.)

Comment: You can do it easily with arara.

Comment: If you are using a build system (see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation) ), most of them have a command to clean the temporary files. Mapping this to a vim shortcut shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: In fact, I use miktex on windows system with vim as the text editor, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you could use

```
:!del *.aux *.log *.out *.bbl *.blg ...
```

in vim and map this to a key you like (F11 for instance) in your vimrc file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a powershell script under windows to this end, I found it years ago here: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2095

The first sentences on this page in German simply says something like »... after I found out how to make powershell work on a certain path, we can easily write a script which deletes all temporary files in a certain folder«. So take this script, save it as "cleaning.ps1" or something alike and start it as powershell script.

It doesn't work under Linux, of course. And you'll have to find out, how to start a powershell script from vim. Good luck!