# Compiling Legrand Orange Book template

Tags: compiling, texmaker, biber

I'm using a template called Legrand Orange Book from http://www.latextemplates.com

I don't know how to accomplish the instructions of the author.
The instructions in the template say:

Compiling this template:
This template uses biber for its bibliography and makeindex for its index.
This means that to update the bibliography and index in this template you
will need to run the following sequence of commands in the template
directory:

1) pdflatex main
2) makeindex main.idx -s StyleInd.ist
3) biber main
4) pdflatex main

I use texmaker (for windows) but I don't know how I can satisfy the 4 conditions, besides I've just downloaded biber and I don't know how to set it up neither. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I think MiKTeX comes with biber installed, just configure texmaker for biber according [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/15717). Choose [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation). BTW, Without editor also one can run the above 1 to 4 commands by opening the [commandline window](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window) inside the downloaded files directory `book_2` to get `main.pdf`