# How should I use BibTeX in TeX Live 2013?

Tags: bibtex

Can anybody simply tell me how should I use BibTeX in TeX Live 2013?
I saved my references in a `.bib` file and I write the following in my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}%Choose a bibliograhpic style
%
author~\cite{Meyer2000}.
%
\bibliography{Master}
\end{document}
```

What I should do afterwards?

I compile it with BibTeX and PDFLaTeX but it does not help.

Comment: The correct sequence is: `latex file.tex`, `bibtex file.aux`, `latex file.tex`, `latex file.tex`.  (Note that the extensions `.tex` and `.aux` are not strictly necessary, but are implied and thereby used even when you omit them.  And of course, you can use any of the following commands in place of `latex`: `latex` (produces `.dvi` by default), `pdflatex` (produces `.pdf` by default), `lualatex`, or `xelatex` -- these last two require the use of a slightly different preamble from 'regular' LaTeX.)

Comment: Use example files from http://andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies Download [bib.tex](http://andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/bib.tex) and [sample.bib](http://andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/sample.bib) to a folder. Run `pdflatex bib`-> `bibtex` -> `pdflatex bib`-> `pdflatex bib` from that folder with proper sequence to get `bib.pdf`

Comment: @jon made an answer with your comment, hope it's ok

Comment: @texenthusiast -- No problem!

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number?

Comment: @Joseph Wright No this is not the same. My question was about Tex Live I saw that question but I did not know that which option I should select instead of latex. There were pdflatex, XeLatex and many other thing in Tex Live but there was no Latex.

Comment: @Ali TeX Live is a TeX distribution, not an editor. I suspect you are talking about the TeXworks editor, bundled as part of TeX Live but not the same thing.

Comment: @Joseph Wright  I am sorry. Yes, I was talking about Texworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8528/jon) has pointed out in his comment.

> The correct sequence is: `latex file.tex`, `bibtex file.aux`, `latex file.tex`, `latex file.tex`. (Note that the extensions `.tex` and `.aux` are not strictly necessary, but are implied and thereby used even when you omit them. And of course, you can use any of the following commands in place of latex: latex (produces `.dvi` by default), `pdflatex` (produces `.pdf` by default), `lualatex`, or `xelatex` -- these last two require the use of a slightly different preamble from 'regular' LaTeX.)

To test a `bibtex` run use example files at http://andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies

Download [bib.tex](http://andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/bib.tex) and [sample.bib](http://andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/sample.bib) to a folder. Run `pdflatex bib`-> `bibtex` -> `pdflatex bib`-> `pdflatex bib` from that folder with proper sequence to get `bib.pdf`

Alternatively one can [automate the compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation)  using `latexmk` and `arara`