# Is there any benefit to compiling LaTeX docs as opposed to using an IDE?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, compiling, workflow, makefile

This post is my first question on StackExchange, so please feel free to tell me how to improve. Here's my typical makefile. I usually use pdflatex, and whatever document viewer is available on the machine I am using. What is usually done in the tex community?

```
all:                                                                            
    pdflatex Thesis.tex                                                         
    bibtex Thesis                                                               
    pdflatex Thesis.tex                                                         
    pdflatex Thesis.tex                                                         
    xdg-open Thesis.pdf
```

I do this to update references. What has been your workflow?

Comment: There are several specific IDE (depending on your operating system, which you do not state). I normally use [`latexmk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk?lang=en), either from my editor (`vim`) or on the command line. You can also check [`arara`](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara)

Comment: I suspect this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation is a duplicate

Comment: I guess the only difference is that I am not necessarily looking for automation but I was wondering if there was a need to do anything else when using vim with latex. I should have been specific in that I am using vim and I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: I use `vim` with [`vimtex`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plug-in, which uses `latexmk` by default. Once set up it works very well and, for reasonable documents, with almost real-time feedback.

Comment: I use vimtex too but have not used latexmk before! Gotta love learning on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Should I edit the post so that your comment answers my post?

Comment: no need. As it is, we can close it as a duplicate. If you change it, it could become a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252555/38080 ;-)

Comment: The big list was definitely the answer I was looking (first duplicate) but the question I asked was worded like the first duplicate. Thanks so much!