# Automatically running nomenclature makeindex (on mac)

Tags: beamer, nomenclature, shell-escape

When I update the nomenclatures in my beamer presentation (file.tex) using texstudio on my mac, I run on the terminal command line:

`makeindex file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o file.nls`

This works, but is a pain.  Is there any way to run this command automatically within the latex code?
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252957/how-to-execute-shell-script-from-latex), I tried adding:

`\immediate\write18{makeindex file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o file.nls}`

but this made the nomenclatures disappear entirely generating:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2018] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning style file /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist

..........done (10 attributes redefined, 3 ignored). Scanning input file file.nlo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Nothing written in file.nls. Transcript written in file.ilg.
```

Comment: [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) ?

Comment: Besides the above mentioned latexmk, there are several other tex automation tools. Latexmk will automatically determind which compilation steps are necessary. If you would like more control over the compilation, you could look at arara, which allows you to specify the necessary steps within your document. Or some other tool from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/36296